# access value from delegate in another class in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am doing networking in iphone, i am able to  connect to a particular server send and receive data. 
My question is how can i access the received data in another class:

For example:
In the code given below,the default delegate stream displays the received data from the particular server as a string output, how can i access it from another class?

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

switch (streamEvent) {

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"Stream opened");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

        if (theStream == inputStream) {

            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;

            while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {

                    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    if (nil != output) {

                        NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                        [self messageReceived:output];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;


    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

        NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
        break;

    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

        [theStream close];
        [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [theStream release];
        theStream = nil;

        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Unknown event");
}
```

}

From the other class, i did the following:

```
SEL mySelector = @selector(stream:handleEvent:);
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:ISIS selector:mySelector       
userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 NSLog(@"Output: %@",ISIS.output);
```

But i getting null for ISIS.output.

Could someone please help me figure this out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than calling `handleEvent` from your other class, you should be passing the data from `handleEvent` to the other class. You can make the other class a delegate, and do something like the following in `handleEvent`-

```
[self.delegate actOnEvent:data]; //where data is whatever you want to pass & actOnEvent is the name of your method
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, i don't get you, could you give me a good example??

Comment: You will need to provide the handleEvent method with a pointer to your other class. Then, simply add the following line [otherClass actOnEvent:output]; after [self messageReceived:output];

Comment: actOnEvent was just a sample name used. Add a method to your other class with whatever name you prefer (actOnEvent or something else), that receives an NSString.

Comment: i got that, thanks Akshay. But isn't there a way that i can know message is received. Because what i need to do is, send message to server, read received message do something and store in an array. I need to do to repeat this atleast 8 times.

Comment: Whenever you will receive a message, handleEvent will hit. Please mark it as the answer if you liked it.

Comment: yeah i know that, but in other Class how will i know handleEvent has been hit??

Comment: Again, handleEvent will call the other class & let it know.

Comment: okay, so u mean to say there isn't anything to check that stream:handleEvent has been triggered??